# Bulk insert with NSFetchedResultsController issue

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a tableview controller. I am populating the tableview data from  `coredata` using `NSFetchedResultsController`.This local db data is coming from server with multiple slot,each api calls brings new 30 items.

First time I am getting 30 item from server api and storing in core data then displaying that using `NSFetchedResultsController` as usual. Now if I reach the last item (30th item) that time I am bringing next slot (`next 30 item`)from server and storing in the same db.

Now how can I `reload` the NSFetchedResultsController so that it will load the next 30 items.

I thought about `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` with `indexpath` but inserting 30 item again and again is not a good approach I think.

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    break;
}
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: If the FRC has a delegate it'll just update automatically when the new data is added to the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert with indexpath but inserting 30 item again and again is not a good approach I think.

This is a good approach. The data is displayed as early as possible as it becomes available. The inserts are controlled, thread safe and animated.

One alternative would be to **delay saving** the managed objects in the background context into which they are inserted and only save after a certain number of records has been processed. A save would then push the changes up into main thread context (provided the background context is set up as a child thereof) which in turn would notify the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to update the UI in **one** animation.

If you have set up your background thread in this way already, this is not very complicated (i.e., you would call `save` *after* the loop that processes your received objects). Otherwise you have to weigh how much you gain by adding complexity.

Comment: How to know that this data is the last data of my db so that I can fetch data from server ?  I want to do that in `willDisplayCell` . If I have 60 records in db and batch size is 10 then on reaching the 60th items I have to fetch from server. How to achieve that?

Comment: posted as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085702/how-to-know-the-last-cell-of-the-uitableview-which-is-populating-from-a-coredata