# How to know the last cell of the UITableView which is populating from a coredata?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using a UITableview with core data.I am calling api and storing data in my local db.Using `fetchedResultsController` table is getting displayed.

From server paginated data is coming each time 20-30 items.So if I reached last cell while scrolling the tableView I should call the api again to get the next items.

This is my `fetchedResultsController`

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (! _fetchedResultsController) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Data"
        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"saved_at" ascending:YES];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

        NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
        self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I have to check here

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //code to check the last item in the core data from `fetchedResultsController`
}
```

So how to check if that record is last record of the db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countForFetchRequest:error:` method on `NSManagedObjectContext` will tell you how many items you're going to see. You can also use the `sections` property on your fetched results controller, querying the (only?) `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` instance for its `numberOfObjects`.

Once you have the number of objects that will be returned, you can compare that to the `indexPath.row` in your `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` call.